# Accessing Array values outside of body or scope in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I declared an array and later assigned values to it. however when I try accessing it in the same viewcontroller, the values are not there. is there a way to make the array values accessible outside of the closures

```
func loadReviews(){
    Firestore.firestore().collection("BusinessReview").whereField("BusinessID", isEqualTo: businessID).limit(to: 3).getDocuments { (querySnapShot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("error\(err)") 
        } else {
            for document in querySnapShot!.documents { 
                self.reviewsArr.append(document.data()["Review"] as! String) 
            }
        }
    } 
    dump(reviewsArr) 
}
```

Although the array was populated after the append code once I do a dump later down its blank. how do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The call to firebase is asynchronous so You need to reload the table inside the completion

```
for document in querySnapShot!.documents { 
    self.reviewsArr.append(document.data()["Review"] as! String) 
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: it'll be always blank as the response from firebase comes after that line is executed do what in answer and the table will get populated

Comment: thank you Sh_Khan, problem solved. you are awesome 